# Heroku/Postgres "ClientAuthentication" Error with Node and node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, node-postgres

I'm in the early stages of setting up an app for development on Heroku using Postgres. A simple version of the problem code in NodeJS is:

```js
const {Client} = require('pg');
const client = new Client({connectionString: 'postgres://{username}:{password}@{host}:5432/{dbname}'});
client.connect();
const result = client.query('SELECT now()');
client.end();
```

`connectionString` being a copy of the string provided from the data.heroku.com's credentials pane, checked and rechecked. I can:

- connect using that connection string from a number of different local apps (e.g., DataGrip)
- use that code (with a different connection string) to connect to a local version of Postgres running in a Docker image

I can't:

- connect from a Node app on my local machine
- connect from a Node app deployed to Heroku

When the code fails against the remote db, node-postgres throws this error:

```js
{
        "length": 168,
        "name": "error",
        "severity": "FATAL",
        "code": "28000",
        "file": "auth.c",
        "line": "496",
        "routine": "ClientAuthentication"
    }
```

Using Node v14.15.1, node-postgres ("pg") 8.5.1

**Update:**
Probably also worth mentioning that I can't find a way to get this connection to *fail* from within Java… the slip is definitely somewhere in Node <-> node-postgres <-> [underlying postgres driver] <-> Heroku (i.e., the db is fine, the connection is fine)… but where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some assistance from Heroku support, I was able to find the solution based on https://help.heroku.com/MDM23G46/why-am-i-getting-an-error-when-i-upgrade-to-pg-8. "Solution 1" did not change anything for me, but "Solution 2" (using `pg-connection-string`) did work.

Fwiw it's worth, I'm also wrapping the SSL with a condition based on the NODE_ENV environment variable, so that the code will work both with the Heroku Postgres instance, but also with the local dev version of that same db. I.e.:

```js
  // centralizing the logic for this so the 'useLocalDb' can be reused
  // in multiple functions in the module (in case the logic needs to change
  // later, among other reasons)
  const useLocalDb = process.env.USE_LOCAL_DB;
  
  // a short version of the working connection code
  const {Pool} = require('pg');
  const {parse} = require('pg-connection-string')
  const config = parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL)
  if (!useLocalDb) {
    config.ssl = {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  }
  const pool = new Pool(config);
```

Comment: I don't understand where this would go in a node application. Could you offer some more explanation?

Answer (score 4):

Adding `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }` when creating the `client` object fixed the issue for me. ([source](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5696#issuecomment-608179879))

```
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: 'postgres://{username}:{password}@{host}:5432/{dbname}',
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
});
```

Maybe try adding `extra: { ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false } }` instead, if the other code does not fix anything ([source](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/822#issuecomment-782037934))

Comment: Hi, @Paul… unfortunately that doesn't work. Fwiw I can't get this connection _fail_ if called from within Java, so I'm inclined to think that this isn't an SSL/cert issue. Come to think of it, that's a data point worth adding to the original post…

Comment: Hi @RiqueW. Do you mean JavaScript? Also, the string 'postgres://{username}:{password}@{host}:5432/{dbname}' is exactly the code you use, or you just wanted to hide the credentials?

Comment: Hey, @Paul… I mean Java itself, not Javascript, just a small utility program to test this connection. Interesting that when I say that I can connect from desktop clients, I think they're all using the JDBC driver, so there's that commonality.

Comment: And yeah, those are just obfuscated variables in the path. I'm initially using the Heroku provided URL,and have been playing with some small variations I thought might help, but so far: nothing

Comment: Hey @Paul… you're answer was _so _ close and *ought* to have worked, imo. I'm not sure why the Heroku support-based answer I've posted below using 'pg-connection-string' does the trick (but I'll take it for now)